# Set unique id when instantiating object (with constructor)

Tags: javascript, object, unique-index

I have a problem I need to solve regarding my Javascript code. When instantiating object (in this case adding new members) I want the members to get unique ids. Below is a simplified version of my code to give you a picture of what I want. What is the best way to do this?

```
function Member(name){

    //unique id code...

    this.getName = function(){
        return name;
    }

    this.setName = function(_name){
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess its easy as:

```
(function() {
    var idcounter = 0;

   function Member(name){
        this.id = idcounter++;
        this.getName = function(){
            return lastName;
        };

        this.setName = function(_name){
            name = _name;
        };
   }

   yournamespace.Member = Member;
}());
```

*yournamespace* should be your application object or whatever. You also could replace it with `window` in a browser, to have the `Member` constructor global.

Comment: Btw you should export Member to global before exiting the anonymous function, the OP might not realize it.

Comment: Great solution. However, I don't really get the namespacing-thing?

Comment: @JasonCraig: well, you should always wrap all of your javascript code into a closured function to avoid clobbering the global object. However, you need to expose the `Member` function to the "outside world" in the example hear. Otherwise you could not use it anywhere outside of the inside-closure (which is created through that wrapping self invoking function)

Comment: @jAndy Ah, thanks for the explanation. But what should/can I name the namespace then?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a (probably) unique id, you could use

```
var id = new Date().getTime();
```

which returns milliseconds since epoch (January 1st 1970).

**EDIT:** I guess I've never encountered those extreme situations described in the comments below in a javascript application, but in those cases this certainly is a bad solution.

Comment: @Esailija If he's likely to create thousands of objects a second, that's probably not a good idea. I've never had a problem with that method myself though, and when I can I like to avoid global variables for counters.

Comment: why do you think a global variable is the only other option? especially with jAndy's answer right under your nose :P

Comment: @Esailija I don't think it's the only other option, but I think it's the most probable option for a person asking that question. How likely is a javascript beginner to be wrapping a closure around his object and not having troubles with scopes?

Comment: he is already creating two closures each time he constructs a  Member, I guess he will have troubles either way :D

Comment: As long as you don't ever set your clock back. If you have something like British Summer Time, and a fair few transactions then the chances of a key not being duplicated start getting surprisingly small.

Comment: @Tony: I'd say that's a pretty rare case for me personally, having a javascript session that's supposed to last +1 hour, but I agree that it's not too far fetched, depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

Use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) that creates a scope for a function. In this scope you define a counter variable. This scope is preserved throughout runtime as long as uniqueId exists. Only the returned function has access to the scope. Each time you call your uniqueId function it adds +1 to the counter in the scope and returns the value.

```
var uniqueId = (() => {
        var counter = 0

        return function() {
            return counter++
        }
    })()

console.log(uniqueId())
console.log(uniqueId())
console.log(uniqueId())
```

Hint: lodash has a uniqueId function also.

Comment: What about if the app is restarted?

Comment: @rfii Then the counter jumps to 0. So it's a solution for runtime only